# Como retornar uma nova array dentro do response.json() em node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, array, node.js, response

Gostaria de saber como faço para retornar uma nova array de objetos no response.json() para ficar visível no insomnia.

Estou recebendo varias informações de uma api e o objetivo é retornar para o meu frontend apenas um array de objetos dentro do response.json() criado por mim.

Portanto quero armazena-las dentro de uma variável.

Porém do jeito que eu fiz, quando faço mais de uma requisição o meu array é duplicado, e eu não quero que isso aconteça.

Esse é o código:

```
let name = "";
let profileImage = "";
let texto = "";
let name2 = "";
let profileImage2 = "";
let texto2 = "";
let arr0 = [];

    

app.get('/teste', (request, response) => {
    T.get('https://******.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=******=1', (err, data, response) => {

        data.map(item => {
            profileImage = item.user.profile_image_url;
            name = item.user.name;
            texto = item.text;
        });
        
        arr0.push({name, texto, profileImage});

    });
    T.get('https://******.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=u*******=1', (err, data, response) => {
    
        data.map(item => {
            name2 = item.user.name;
            texto2 = item.text;
            profileImage2 = item.user.profile_image_url;
        });
        
        arr0.push({name2, texto2, profileImage2});
    
    });    

    
    return response.json(arr0);
});
```

Obs: Enviei apenas os trechos mais relevantes do código!

Comment: Cara, ficou um pouco difícil de interpretar o código sem o contexto completo. Por exemplo: esse bloco de código é uma função só? Qual é o retorno que você está tendo na variável arr0?

Nesse caso em específico acho que o seu problema não tem nada a ver com o Node, ok? é mais uma coisa de Javascript mesmo. O método padrão do JS para concatenar arrays é o Concat.

Comment: @M.Bertolazo ele bagunçou os nomes das variável, mas, rapaz, é a mesma coisa

Comment: os dois T.get fazem a mesma inserções... duplicando...

Comment: a unica diferença é que a duplicata tem o nome das propriedades terminado com '2'